# Need to bypass jquery toggle function

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need to be able to bypass the first function of a toggle and I was wondering how the jquery toggle works?

I understand that if I click on something, the first function is carried out and then when I click on it again, the second function is carried out.

What I need to be able to do is to bypass the first function and go directly to the second one.

Reason I am doing this is that the state of a button has been changed by another event that's happened. When I now click on that button for the first time, it assumes that it's the first time it's been clicked and will carry out the first function when I need it to carry out the second function.

Is there a way around this? If the jQuery toggle function equates to a true or false, then surely I should be able to check this and call on the correct script?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the other event doesn't *always* fire before the first toggle, otherwise you could just reverse the functions.

Could you change your other event to fire the toggle? If the other event is performing the same task, then this would be the way to go.

```
  // From within the other event's handler
$(someselector).click();  // to fire the toggle
```

Otherwise, you could use `.data()` to place a flag on the element to check if the `toggle()` has fired yet. If it hasn't, then have the first function test to see if the element has been modified by the other event.

```
$(someselector).toggle(
    function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if( !$th.data('toggled') ) {  // Check if toggle has not yet run
            $th.data('toggled', true);    // If not, set flag it to show it has run
            if( some_test_to_see_if_modified_externally ) {
                $th.click() // fire the second toggle
                return;     // return if element has been modified externally
            }
        } 
        // otherwise run the normal code  
    },
    function() {
        // your normal code
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Patrick,

Thanks for sending me this example. I will use it if I don't come right, but if you can show me how the other function can call the toggle, that would be awesome because it would clear up a lot of clutter!

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Sixfoot - Yes, just use the first code example I gave near the top of my answer. A `toggle()` is just a `click` event. So when your other event makes the changes to the element that has the the `toggle` event, just perform a `click()` event on it: `$(someselector).click();` This will fire the toggle as though it had been clicked.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and get back to you! Thanks Patrick for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable outside of the toggle function: `var isFirstToggle = true;`.

Then in your toggle callback just return if it is equal to true;

```
var isFirstToggle = true;
$("#myId").toggle(function(){
   if (isFirstToggle === true){
      isFirstToggle = false;
      return;
}, function(){
   //do stuff on second toggle.
});
```

Let me know your thoughts and if this seems appropriate.  There is probably cleaner ways to handle it, but this should work quick-n-dirty.

Comment: This would *always* disable the first toggle. This may not be desired. If that was the case, you could just reverse the order of the two functions. :o)